# A problem from Zorich

Tags: analysis

I am trying to read *Mathematical Analysis I* by Zorich on my own. Here is an exercise that I could not solve:

> For all $l \in \mathbb{R}$ that is not of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a continuous function $f: [0, 1] \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0) = f(1)$ and the graph of $f$ contains no horizontal chord with length $l$.

I was wondering how to prove this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who is Zorich?? Is it the book on Analysis 1?

Comment: Yes! It is Mathematical Analysis I by Zorich.

Comment: Chapter 4 I think, which is about continuity of functions.

Comment: What is a horizontal chord?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of horizontal chord? Is this just a horizontal line connecting any two points of the graph or something else?

Comment: It is basically saying that there does not exist any x in [0, 1] such that f(x) agrees with f(x + l).

Comment: So yes, a horizontal chord is just a horizontal line connecting two points of the graph.

Comment: Please change the title to be more specific (or at least to not include grammar errors)!